# Group collide in Alien invasion

Tags: python, sprite

I have created the game AlienInvasion on Python crash course but the bullets are not hitting the aliens in the topmost row. Rather than clear the topmost row and create a new fleet, the game creates a new fleet on top of the topmost row. [Alien invasion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHNLN.png)The topmost row is still visible in the background and the aliens there are not getting cleared from the screen.

Here is my code

alien_invasion.py

```
import sys

import pygame

from settings import Settings
from alien import Alien
from ship import Ship
from bullet import Bullet

class AlienInvasion():
    """overall class to manage game assests and behaviours"""
    
    def __init__(self):
        """Initialize the game and create resources"""
        pygame.init()
        self.settings = Settings()
        
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((0, 0), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
        self.settings.screen_width = self.screen.get_rect().width
        self.settings.screen_height - self.screen.get_rect().height
        pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")
        
        self.ship = Ship(self)
        self.bullets = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.aliens = pygame.sprite.Group()
        
        self._create_fleet()
        
    def run_game(self):
        """starts the main loop of the game"""
        while True:
            self._check_events()
            self.ship.update()
            self._update_bullets()
            self._update_aliens()
            self._update_screen()
            
    def _check_events(self):
        """responds to key presses and mouse events"""
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                self._check_keydown_events(event)
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                self._check_keyup_events(event)
                
    def _check_keydown_events(self, event):
        """respnods to keypresses"""
        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            self.ship.moving_right = True
        elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            self.ship.moving_left = True
        elif event.key == pygame.K_q:
            sys.exit()
        elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
            self._fire_bullet()
            
    def _check_keyup_events(self, event):
        """Responds to key releases"""
        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            self.ship.moving_right = False
        elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            self.ship.moving_left = False
            
    def _fire_bullet(self):
        """create a new bullet and add it to the group"""
        if len(self.bullets) < self.settings.bullets_allowed:
            new_bullet = Bullet(self)
            self.bullets.add(new_bullet)
            
    def _update_bullets(self):
        """update position of bullets and get rid of old ones"""
        #update bullet position
        self.bullets.update()
        
        #get rid of bullets that have dissapeared
        for bullet in self.bullets.copy():
            if bullet.rect.bottom <= 0:
                self.bullets.remove(bullet)
        #check of any collision between aliens and bullets
        collision = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(self.bullets, self.aliens, True, True)
                
    def _update_aliens(self):
        """ chekcs if fleet is at an end them moves aliens"""
        self.check_fleet_edges()
        self.aliens.update()
    
    def get_number_aliens_x(self, alien_width):
        """Find the number that can fit in a row"""
        alien = Alien(self)
        alien_width, alien_height = alien.rect.size
        available_space_x = self.settings.screen_width - (2*alien_width)
        number_of_aliens = int(available_space_x // (2*alien_width))
        return number_of_aliens
    
    def get_number_rows(self, ship_height, alien_height):
        """determine the availalbe space vertically"""
        alien = Alien(self)
        ship_height = self.ship.rect.height
        alien_width, alien_height = alien.rect.size
        available_space_y = (self.settings.screen_height -
                            (3 * alien_height) - ship_height)
        #determine number of rows
        number_rows = int(available_space_y // (2 * alien_height))
        return number_rows
    
    def _create_fleet(self):
        """creates a full fleet of aliens"""
        #create an alien 
        alien = Alien(self)
        #create a fleet
        ship_height = self.ship.rect.height
        alien_width, alien_height = alien.rect.size
        number_rows = self.get_number_rows(ship_height, alien_height)
        number_of_aliens = self.get_number_aliens_x(alien_width)
        for row_number in range(number_rows):
            for alien_number in range(number_of_aliens):
                self._create_alien(alien_number, row_number)
                        
    def _create_alien(self, alien_number, row_number):
        """creates an alien and places it in a row"""
        alien = Alien(self)
        alien_width, alien_height = alien.rect.size
        alien_width = alien.rect.width
        alien.x = alien_width + 2*alien_width * alien_number
        alien.rect.x = alien.x
        alien.rect.y = alien.rect.height + 2*alien.rect.height * row_number
        self.aliens.add(alien)

    def check_fleet_edges(self):
        """check if any alien has hit the edge"""
        for alien in self.aliens.sprites():
            if alien.check_edges():
                self.change_fleet_direction()
                break
            
    def change_fleet_direction(self):
        """drop the entirefleetand change direction"""
        for alien in self.aliens.sprites():
            alien.rect.y += self.settings.fleet_drop_speed
        self.settings.fleet_direction *= -1
                
    

        
    def _update_screen(self):
        """updates images ont eh screen and flip to the new screen"""
        self.screen.fill(self.settings.bg_color)
        self.ship.blitme()
        for bullet in self.bullets.sprites():
            bullet.draw_bullet()
        self.aliens.draw(self.screen)
        
        pygame.display.flip()
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    #make an instance of the game and run it
    ai = AlienInvasion()
    ai.run_game()
```

alien.py

```
import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Sprite

class Alien(Sprite):
    """ represents the aliens inthe game"""
    
    def __init__(self, ai_game):
        """initializes the alien for the fleet"""
        super().__init__()
        self.screen = ai_game.screen
        self.settings = ai_game.settings
        
        #load the alien
        self.image = pygame.image.load('images/alien.bmp')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        
        #alien starting positon
        self.rect.x = self.rect.width
        self.rect.y = self.rect.height
        
        #Store alien exact horizontal position 
        self.x = float(self.rect.x)
    
    def check_edges(self):
        """check if the any alien is at the edge"""
        screen_rect = self.screen.get_rect()
        if self.rect.right >= screen_rect.right or self. rect.left <= 0:
            return True
            
    def update(self):
        """move alien to right or left"""
        self.x += (self.settings.alien_speed *
                        self.settings.fleet_direction)
        self.rect.x = self.x
```

bullet.py

```
import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Sprite

class Bullet(Sprite):
    """ class to manage bullets"""
    
    def __init__(self, ai_game):
        """initialzie the bullets attributes"""
        super().__init__()
        self.screen = ai_game.screen
        self.settings = ai_game.settings
        self.color = self.settings.bullet_color
        
        #create the bullet at 0,0 then set correct position
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, self.settings.bullet_width,
            self.settings.bullet_height)
        self.rect.midtop = ai_game.ship.rect.midtop
        
        #store bullet position as a decimal value
        self.y = float(self.rect.y)
        
    def update(self):
        """Move bullets up the screen"""
        #update the decimal position of the bullet
        self.y -= self.settings.bullet_speed
        #update the rect positon
        self.rect.y = self.y
        
    def draw_bullet(self):
        """draws the bullets on the screen"""
        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, self.color, self.rect)
```

ship.py

```
import pygame

class Ship():
    """creates a ship """
    
    def __init__(self, ai_settings):
        """initializes the ship and its starring position"""
        
        self.ai_settings = ai_settings
        
        #load the ship image and get its rect
        
        self.image = pygame.image.load('images/ship.bmp')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
        
        #start each new ship at the bottom of the screen
        self.rect.centerx = self.screen_rect.centerx
        self.rect.bottom = self.screen_rect.bottom
        
        #sore a decimal value for the ship's center
        self.center = float(self.rect.centerx)
        
        #Movement flag
        self.moving_right = False
        self.moving_left = False
        
    def update(self):
        """update ships center value based on the movement flags"""
        if self.moving_right and self.rect.right < self.screen_rect.right:
            self.center += self.ai_settings.ship_speed_factor
        if self.moving_left and self.rect.left > 0:
            self.center -= self.ai_settings.ship_speed_factor
        
        #update rect object from self.center
        self.rect.centerx = self.center
        
    def blitme(self):
        """Draws the ship and its current location"""
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

I have tried tweaking the number of rows but it did not change anything.
Can anyone see where my mistake is??

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the line `alien.rect.y = alien.rect.height = 2 * alien.rect.height * row_number` in the `_create_alien` method to `alien.rect.y = alien.rect.height + 2 * alien.rect.height * row_number` should solve the issue.

Here is the updated method:

```
 def _create_alien(self, alien_number, row_number):
     """creates an alien and places it in a row"""
     alien = Alien(self)
     alien_width, alien_height = alien.rect.size
     alien_width = alien.rect.width
     alien.x = alien_width + 2*alien_width * alien_number
     alien.rect.x = alien.x
     alien.rect.y = alien.rect.height + 2 * alien.rect.height * row_number
     self.aliens.add(alien)
```

Also there is a typo in the definition of your Alien class, it should be
`class Alien(Sprite):` not `class Alien(Spralien.ite):`